# Possibly processing same message in DB Queue (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We experience sometimes that a message in our job queue is processed two times. In our system environment there is two services that can process messages from the queue table T_JOB_DIRECT.

Below you can see the stored procedure that is called by the service that is suppose to pick a message from the queue.

Can you see if there are some obvious mistake made that would make it possible for the two services to pick the same message from the T_JOB_DIRECT table?

```
CREATE       PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetOneBatchJobForExec]
@sMachineName NVARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN  
DECLARE @JOB_DIRECT_ID INTEGER

  SET NOCOUNT ON
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

  IF RTRIM(ISNULL(@sMachineName, '')) = '' BEGIN
    RAISERROR('@sMachineName parameter must be supplied!',16,1)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @JOB_DIRECT_ID = 0
    WHILE @JOB_DIRECT_ID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
      -- If there is an job that has been marked for this service then return that.
      SET @JOB_DIRECT_ID = NULL
      SELECT TOP 1 @JOB_DIRECT_ID = JOB_DIRECT_ID FROM dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT WHERE IN_PROCESS_BY = @sMachineName
      IF @JOB_DIRECT_ID IS NULL
      BEGIN

        -- else take highest prioritized job that is free
        SELECT TOP 1 @JOB_DIRECT_ID = JOB_DIRECT_ID
        FROM dbo.T_JOB_TYPE AS JY 
          INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_TYPE_ON_INST AS JTI 
            ON JY.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
          INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT AS JD 
            ON JD.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
          AND JD.INST_ID = JTI.INST_ID
        WHERE JD.IN_PROCESS_BY IS NULL AND JD.START_DATETIME < GETDATE()
        ORDER BY JD.START_DATETIME DESC, JTI.PRIORITY DESC

        IF @JOB_DIRECT_ID IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
          --Mark the job as taken and pick it up the next loop OR if update misses (someone else got it before) then get anotehr i next loop.
          UPDATE dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT SET IN_PROCESS_BY = @sMachineName WHERE JOB_DIRECT_ID = @JOB_DIRECT_ID AND IN_PROCESS_BY IS NULL
        END
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        -- Return job information for the selected job.
        SELECT TOP 1 JD.*, JY.JOB_NAME
        FROM dbo.T_JOB_TYPE AS JY INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_TYPE_ON_INST AS JTI 
            ON   JY.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
          INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT AS JD 
            ON   JD.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
          AND JD.INST_ID = JTI.INST_ID
        WHERE JOB_DIRECT_ID = @JOB_DIRECT_ID

        --Set ID NULL to exit the loop
        SET @JOB_DIRECT_ID = NULL
      END
    END  --LOOP

  END  --IF RAISE

END
```

**EDIT**
I got some feedback from the original creator of the procedure and he says that the reason that the procedure should be able to be executed without a transaction but still manage a race condition.

The race should be managed by the UPDATE.

```
UPDATE dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT SET IN_PROCESS_BY = @sMachineName 
WHERE JOB_DIRECT_ID = @JOB_DIRECT_ID AND IN_PROCESS_BY IS NULL
```

it should only pick one job with the same ID and if IN_PROCESS_BY = NULL. That is only be able to pick the job if and only if noone else has picked it between the select and update.

The procedures should be able to handle a race and he don't think you have a valid point there. 
Without "AND IN_PROCESS_BY IS NULL" we sure would have a problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Ben Thul above I changed the stored procedure to take advantage of the OUTPUT clause. The original sp was written before the OUTPUT clause was introduced in SQL Server.

Here is the final new version.

```
CREATE       PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetOneBatchJobForExec]
@sMachineName NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

with cte as (
    SELECT TOP(1) JD.*, JY.JOB_NAME
    FROM dbo.T_JOB_TYPE AS JY 
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_TYPE_ON_INST AS JTI 
            ON JY.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT AS JD WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
            ON JD.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
        AND JD.INST_ID = JTI.INST_ID
    WHERE (JD.IN_PROCESS_BY IS NULL OR JD.IN_PROCESS_BY = @sMachineName) AND JD.START_DATETIME < GETDATE()
    ORDER BY JD.IN_PROCESS_BY DESC, JD.START_DATETIME DESC, JTI.PRIORITY DESC
)
UPDATE cte 
SET IN_PROCESS_BY = @sMachineName
OUTPUT inserted.JOB_DIRECT_ID, inserted.JOB_TYPE_ID, inserted.INST_ID, inserted.JOB_QUEUE_ID, inserted.JOB_DATA, inserted.REG_DATETIME, 
        inserted.REG_USER_ID, inserted.JOB_TIME_ID, inserted.IN_PROCESS_BY, inserted.START_DATETIME, deleted.JOB_NAME

END
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a race condition. Specifically, there is time between when you select the row and when you update it as "in process". You can get around this with some query hints and wrapping the select and update in a transaction. Your select can look something like:

```
IF @JOB_DIRECT_ID IS NULL
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SELECT TOP 1 @JOB_DIRECT_ID = JOB_DIRECT_ID
    FROM dbo.T_JOB_TYPE AS JY 
    INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_TYPE_ON_INST AS JTI 
       ON JY.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT AS JD with (updlock, rowlock, readpast)
       ON JD.JOB_TYPE_ID = JTI.JOB_TYPE_ID
       AND JD.INST_ID = JTI.INST_ID
    WHERE JD.IN_PROCESS_BY IS NULL 
       AND JD.START_DATETIME < GETDATE()
    ORDER BY JD.START_DATETIME DESC, JTI.PRIORITY DESC;

    IF @JOB_DIRECT_ID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Mark the job as taken and pick it up the next loop 
        -- OR if update misses (someone else got it before) 
        -- then get another in next loop.
        UPDATE dbo.T_JOB_DIRECT 
        SET IN_PROCESS_BY = @sMachineName 
        WHERE JOB_DIRECT_ID = @JOB_DIRECT_ID
           AND IN_PROCESS_BY IS NULL
    END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

As an aside, I'd add a unique filtered index on the t_job_direct table on the in_process_by column where the value is not null if you don't already have one. That will prevent more than one row being in process by a given machine at any time.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your time to investigate this! I got some feedback from the original creator of the procedure. Please see below EDIT in the original post above!

Comment: Perhaps. But the problem is that you're getting a `@JOB_DIRECT_ID` in a separate select and so two or more processes can grab the same row at the same time. Another way to manage this would be to use an OUTPUT clause on your update and skip the select all together.

Comment: Thank you for enlighten me about the OUTPUT clause Ben. Helped us a lot.